# Need left large curly bracket that allows alignment in align environment

Tags: tex-core

I know that `\begin{cases}\end{cases}` can give me large left bracket spanning multiple lines, but it does not work well when I want to align equations inside cases with that outside using `&`. For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
x&=1\\
y&=2\\
&\begin{cases}a&=3\\b&=4\end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `align` environment treats `cases` as a whole object, but I want to align the equal signs both inside and outside of `cases`. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a hack; hopefully, someone else will find a better answer. Anyways, the inner and outer environments are aligned around `=`, so you can treat them separately and manually adjust one with something like `\hskip`. It does look weird with `cases` environment, so I used `aligned` instead and inserted a big curly brace with `\hbox` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
x&=1\\
y&=2\\
&\hskip -.45cm\hbox{$\biggl\{$} \begin{aligned}a&=3\\b&=4\end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By use of the `\biggl{` and `split` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 x  & = 1   \\
 y  & = 2   \\
\biggl\{\begin{split}
    a & = 3 \\
    b & = 4
        \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]