# Large curly bracket on the left of alignat environment

Tags: brackets, alignat

I have read this post [Need left large curly bracket that allows alignment in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/582983/290833) and known the `cases` environment. Now I have an `align` environment and hope that there is a large curly bracket on the left of all the three equations, just like what `cases` does, but it labels all of the equations separately. Thanks for any reply.

My code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat}{2}
         & \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=a^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+A, && \qquad 0<x<l,t>0 \\
         & u|_{x=0}=0,u|_{x=l}=B, && \qquad t>0 \\
         & u|_{t=0}=u_t|_{t=0}=0. && \qquad 0\leq x\leq l
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

And the result I want is like:
[image]

Comment: @cabohah Ah, I have noticed the `cases` package before, but it seemed to work badly with some settings of my document, so I thought this package did not meet my needs. I just tried and finally it worked well on a fresh document, and it actually solve my problem. Thanks for your reply.